# MvcContrib namespace not visible in Views

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib

I use MvcContrib Portable Areas, everything is ok, but I decided to use MvcContrib Grid. I have MvcContrib.dll and MvcContrib.FluentHtml.dll referenced to all projects of my solution.
The problem is that Views don't see MvcContrib even though it is is referenced.

@using MvcContrib result is: "The type or namespace MvcContrib could not be found". In the root (parent) project everything is ok.

I use .NET 4.0 and MVC 3.0

I reference my Web.config from portable areas Views folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
<section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
<section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="MvcContrib"/>
    <add namespace="MvcContrib.UI"/>
    <add namespace="MvcContrib.UI.Html"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Globalization" />
    <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>

<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>

<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

  </assemblies>
</compilation>

</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

<handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by adding the MVC Contrib reference to my **root** module and to the **areas** modules **too**!

Also you may need to add the following codes to your views `web.config` where ever you used this Third-Party component.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="..." />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
     <namespaces>
     <add namespace="MvcContrib"/>
     <add namespace="MvcContrib.UI.Grid"/>
     <add...
```

I hope this would help